# Cannot Use parentNode with DomXpath in PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I'm having difficulty using parentNode with DomXpath.

```
<?php 
$html = <<<STR
        <div id="bar">
            <p>item1</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="foo">item2</li>
                <li>item3</li>
                <li>item4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
STR;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
$nodeFoo = $xpath->query("//*[@id='bar']//*[@class='foo']"); 
echo $nodeFoo->item(0)->nodeValue;

$nodeClimb = $nodeFoo->parentNode; // causes an error
echo $nodeClimb.nodeName;
?>
```

I expected that the last line yields 'ul' which is the parent node name of the retrieved node, $nodeFoo. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo on your last line: `echo $nodeClimb.nodeName;` should be `echo $nodeClimb->nodeName;`

However, your main problem is something that you've spotted on one line but not on the next: the XPath query returns not a single `DOMNode`, but an instance of `DOMNodeList` containing all the matches for that query.

So just as you have selected the first item in the list to echo (`echo $nodeFoo->item(0)->nodeValue;`), you need to select an item to assign as the parent (`$nodeClimb = $nodeFoo->item(0)->parentNode;`).

Comment: In my actual script, I started getting the error `Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()` although the code structure is the same. I wonder why.